# Is the composition of two plane waves also a plane wave?

Tags: waves, plasma-physics, dispersion

I'm really interesting to know more about Plasma physics for waves , it comes in my mind to ask this question related to [dispertion relation topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) exactly plane waves , It is well known that the plane waves defined by the following mathematical formula : $A(x,t)= A_0 \exp (2i\pi (\frac{x-vt}{\lambda}))$

$A$ is the amplitude of the wave, $A_0 = A(0,0)$

$x$ is a position along the wave's direction of travel, and
$t$ is the time at which the wave is described.
Now my question here is : if we take other plane wave:$A'(x,t)= A_0 \exp (2i\pi (\frac{x-vt}{\lambda}))$
$A'(x,t)= A'_0 \exp (2i\pi (\frac{x-vt}{\lambda}))$ and we look to do mathematical composition of $ A'$  and $ A $ like this : $(A'\circ A)(x,t) $, Now does this composition give us a plane wave ? and if it is What about its new parameters ?

Comment: Composition is meaningless here. Composition means taking the output of one function and using it as the input for another function. That doesn’t work here because the output is not $x$ and $t$. Perhaps you are confusing composition with superposition, which means simply adding the two waves together?

Comment: @G.Smith, I do not mean superposition, But I meant what  composition operation give us between two  plane waves and pleas could u explaine me more why the output  is not x and y ?

Comment: The output is the intensity of the wave at a point in space and time. That  intensity is neither $x$ nor $t$ and cannot be fed into the other wave formula.

Comment: If you think composition has meaning here, try writing down $(A'\circ A)(x,t) $ as an explicit function of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: I understand that in this case the composition w'd be constant

Comment: With all due respect, your understanding is wrong. Talking about the composition of these two functions is literally nonsense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition.

Comment: @G.Smith, I said that since you calimed that the output is intensity wave not depend to x and y , My problem am not familiar for interpretation physics ? What about if we fix x or t ? does this composition work ?

Comment: Forget about physics. The output is one complex number. The inputs are two real numbers. Can you see the problem? If you are planning to respond that one complex number is equivalent to two real numbers, I’m planning to respond that that is meaningless here. The real and imaginary parts of the wave intensity have nothing to do with $x$ and $t$.

Comment: Thanks for that it is very clear now, then the sense w'd be in adding two waves as you claimed above

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Please edit the question to reflect this correction, so that others don't have to read the whole comment thread to understand what you're asking.